# How to get the physical controller class file path of the executing action method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Assume the current executing action method is Index() in Home controller. From within Index(), how to obtain the physical file path of the Home controller? Assume we don't know the file structure until runtime.

Comment: possible dublicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773798/controller-path-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Rippo, I think that's what he's shooting for

Comment: @hunter, yes I see... for testing purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The physical file (Controller\Home.cs) might not exist, since the controller is compiled into a .dll, and by convention, is stored in the bin folder.

If it is the .dll you want, probably in the bin folder, or use [GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx) from within the controller.

You can find the name of the controller using:

```
Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

You can store the location of the .cs files in your Web.Config, that would be enough to find them. (Beware of partial .cs files).

Finding the controller method would be the next step, since finding a method with the right name is not enough. You have to match the parameters and attribute (HttpPost / ActionName).

Comment: can we force MVC project to work as WebForm website? I mean, the cs files are still in the site dir?

Comment: The Views (.cshtml / .aspx) are physically stored on the server. The Controllers are compiled (these you can compare to the codebehind files). But it is wrong to add controller logic in the View. What is it you want to do?

Comment: My scenario is to build a mvc project with a master page containing 2 buttons. One button with caption "Show Controller Code" will let the visitor know the controller code and the other one with caption "Show View Code" will display the view code. It looks like W3C tutorial by experiment site but mine is in read only mode.

Comment: thank for your answer. I think this question will never be solved because pre-compilation of controller is a must.

Comment: And since controllers can be big (and partial), showing the right stuff (=method) to the user would kind of involve building your own C# compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This will help: [Get the Assembly path C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917053/get-the-assembly-path-c)

Comment: thanks. If controller class must be compiled before doployment, unlike webform site which can be deployed without pre-compiled, my question in this topic is no longer solvable.